# Group by column and write each group of strings to text file using Apache Spark and Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a .csv file with the columns id and a couple of string columns. I want to group by id and then write all of the values from string_column1 to a text file (each value on a new row). Finally, I want the name of the text file to be "allstrings"+id.
I'm using Apache Spark with Java.

I've tried to use groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("string_column1")) but I get "The method collect_list(String) is undefined for the type Main".
I don't know how to name the text files using the distinct values from the id column.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.WARN);

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("testingSql")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read()
        .option("header", true)
        .csv("src/main/resources/maininput.csv");

        // make a separate .csv file for each group of strings (grouped by id),
        // with each string on a new line
        // and the name of the file should be "allstrings"+id
        RelationalGroupedDataset result = dataset.groupBy("id")
                .agg(collect_list("string_column1"))
                .?????????;



        spark.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can partition data on write, it will create separated directories for each group `id`
and name of each folder will be in format **column_name**=**value**.

`df.write.partitionBy("id").csv("output_directory")`

Then you can use `org.apache.hadoop.fs._` to rename files from each group directory.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why I'm getting "The method collect_list(String) is undefined for the type Main" when using groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("string_column1"))? Is this a scala method? What can I use in Java?

Comment: You should import sql.functions to use collect_list or do smoething like that: `.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list("string_column1"))`

Comment: Hi, I'm using this method and it's very slow. Is there any other way?